# No decoder error using MongoDB and Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a struct that I am storing within MongoDB

```
type Step struct {
    Name           string
    CompensateFunc interface{}
    Error          error       `bson:"error,omitempty"`
    Result         interface{} 
}
```

The struct gets stored in Mongo fine but when I try and fetch it I get the following error:

`error decoding key steps.0.error: no decoder found for error`

Is there something I need to do to store Golang errors within a MongoDB?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is because Mongo can't decode interfaces out of the box, it can only decode simple types.

To fix the error I stored the underlying error string on the struct instead

```
type Step struct {
    Error  string 
}
```